# Possible to format a column when using "select *"?

Tags: sql, oracle

I had this table in oracle db, consist of 100+ columns:

```
ID number PK, CREATEDON date, C0 varchar2, C1 varchar2, ... ,c100 varchar2
0, 2012-12-19 05:18:21, 0, 1, ... ,100
```

I wanted to select them all with `CREATEDON` formated, so I wrote this query:

```
select *, to_char(CREATEDON, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from SOME_TABLE;
```

But then it threw out an error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`.

Since I didn't want to write `select ID, to_char(CREATEDON, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), col0, col1,...,col100` in every query, I went on to try another one:

```
select a.*, to_char(b.CREATEDON, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from SOME_TABLE a
join SOME_TABLE b on (a.ID = B.ID);
```

It worked fine, but should this join slow the whole query down as rows in `SOME_TABLE` increase?

So, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you should probably alias the `to_char` call, eg `to_char(CREATEDON, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS co_formatted FROM SOME_TABLE...`

Comment: Which SQL client are you using? In SQL*Plus you can define column formats using the `column` command. For other SQL clients, check out how they format timestamp/date columns (some honor the NLS_xxx settings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an Oracle-specific issue. Try specifying the table for the `*` operator:

```
select SOME_TABLE.*, to_char(CREATEDON, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from SOME_TABLE;
```

See also [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8386e/10)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

`select a.*, to_char(CREATEDON, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from SOME_TABLE a;`

Answer (score 1):

It is an oracle specific issue. The problem is when using the general `*` operator they don't like you selecting any other column.

So suggesstion

```
select x.*, to_char(CREATEDON, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from SOME_TABLE x;
```